# How to combine value errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, valueerror, raise

I have two function which check correctness of datas. Both function raise ValueError. Those funcions are executing in "for" loop so when one function will raise error, second will not be executed. Is there any possibility to combine both ValueErrors and return them via third function?
Ex:

```
datas = [4, "is", "data", None]

def func(word):
    if not word:
        raise ValueError("Wrong data!")

def func1(word):
    if type(data) != str:
        raise ValueError("Data isn't string!")

for data in datas:
    func(data)
    func1(data)
```

What I want as output:

```
ValueError: Wrong data!
ValueError: Data isn't string!
```

I'm not sure if it possible with ValueErrors but maybe there is some other way of combine errors?

Comment: split into 2 separate for loops

Comment: See my answer, but I'm not sure why you expect to get `Wrong data!` first. The errors will happen in the opposite order.

Comment: Order doesn't matter in this case so don't pay attention to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least hacky way to achieve this would be to accumulate the exceptions in a list, then handle the errors as you see fit:

```py
datas = [4, "is", "data", None]

errors = []

def func(word):
    if not word:
        raise ValueError("Wrong data!")

def func1(word):
    if type(data) != str:
        raise ValueError("Data isn't string!")

for data in datas:
    try:
        func(data)
        func1(data)
    except ValueError as e:
        errors.append(e)

for error in errors:
     print(error)
```

will output

```
Data isn't string!
Wrong data!
```